# Combing cell values within variable?

Tags: r

im sure this question already exists on this site, but I'm having trouble finding it.

I want to collapse certain values within a variable.
For example, I have a variable called `Race`. Within the `Race` variable, I want to combine the observations `Refused` and `Unknown` since there are only a few observations of each, and I think its fair to treat them the same for my analysis.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
library(dplyr) 
df$Race[df$Race %in% c("Refused", "Unknown") ] <- “Refused/Unknown"
```